# Interpreter: Python built-in functions not defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was going through the basics of Python, and testing out some built-in functions in the interpreter. The documentation I was looking at was talking about Python 3... I am using Python 2.7.3.

```
>>> x = '32456'
>>> x
'32456'
>>> isalpha(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'isalpha' is not defined
```

I did some research and it does not seem that `isalpha()` is limited to only Python 3... I also cannot use `sin(3.3)` even after doing `import math`

So why am I seeing an error? Is there some other module I have to import for these functions to work?

Comment: `isalpha` is not a function. It's a method: `x.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isalpha()` is not a function but a method of the `str` type. If you have to, you can extract it as an unbound method and give it a name as a function:

```
>>> "hello".isalpha()
True
>>> "31337".isalpha()
False
>>> isalpha = str.isalpha
>>> isalpha("hello")
True
>>> isalpha("31337")
False
```

Functions in an imported module are members of that module. To pull a function into the main namespace, use the `from` statement:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(3.3)
-0.1577456941432482
>>> from math import cos
>>> cos(3.3)
-0.9874797699088649
```

Now why does Python work this way? Both the `math` module and the `logging` module have a function called `log()`, but they do very different things.

```
>>> import math, logging
>>> help(math.log)

log(...)
    log(x[, base])

    Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
    If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.

>>> help(logging.log)

log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)
    Log 'msg % args' with the integer severity 'level' on the root logger. If
    the logger has no handlers, call basicConfig() to add a console handler
    with a pre-defined format.
```

If all imported symbols went straight to the main namespace the way they do when you `from math import *`, a program wouldn't be able to use both modules' `log()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

`isalpha` is a method for strings, not a builtin function as you suppose.

```
>>> '34r'.isalpha()
False
>>> '45'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'rt'.isalpha()
True
```

To use `sin`, you need to import: `from math import sin`

Comment: fair enough, what about sin(3.3) telling me that `'sin' is not defined`?

Comment: You need to import: `from math import sin`

Answer (score 0):

For `sin(3.3)` you have to `import math`, then call `math.sin(3.3)`.